# Creating a google_sql_user with terraform always recreates the resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

When ever I am running a `terraform plan` using the following:

```
resource "google_sql_user" "users" {
    name     = "me"
    instance = "${google_sql_database_instance.master.name}"
    host = "me.com"
    password = "changeme"
    }
```

This only happens when I am running this a Postgres instance on Google Cloud SQL.
Terraform always outputs that the plan will create a user, even though it's already created. I'm using `terraform version 0.11.1`. Is there something that i'm missing? I tried setting the `id` value, however there it still recretes itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the terraform state of the user was not being added, the cause seemed to be that when using postgres, the value `host = "me.com"` is not required, but causes problems if it's left there.

Once that was removed, then the terraform state will be correct.